# How does Javascript's ability to use undeclared functions as objects help in dividing a task between computers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, computer-science

I recently read [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html) tries to explain how JavaScript's ability to manipulate functions could be used to let every computer in the world to do a small part in processing all the information on the internet. The way I understand it is this:

```
function map(fn, a)
{
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = fn(a[i]);
    }
}
```

the function `map` allows you to call a function to every element in an array quickly

```
map( function(x){return x*2;}, a );
```

and JS allows you to call a function without declaring it. The premise is that if all data on the internet was stored as an array you can (somehow using `map`) split the task of making some specific change to every item in the array between several CPUs or all the computers of the world.

This is the part I do not understand - why do you need `map` or JS's array manipulation to do this? Couldn't you just send every computer a section of the array, send them the function to run on every element in the array, and have them convert the array *without* needing to execute `map` or any number of wacky function usage?

Sure, using a function as an object seems convenient, but why is this at all integral to the task of splitting tasks between CPUs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are jumping to the wrong conclusions here. Joel is not advocating to use JavaScript to "*let every computer in the world to do a small part in processing all the information on the internet*". He is using JavaScript as a language of choice to demonstrate the functionality of `map` and `reduce` functions (which, btw, could be defined much more generic than only for arrays). He then does leave the realm of JavaScript entirely, musing that programming languages need a certain level of abstraction ([first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)) to be of any help:

> *Programming languages with first-class functions let you find more opportunities for abstraction, which means your code is smaller, tighter, more reusable, and more scalable.*

That [`map` and `reduce`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) are so useful as a concept (without any particular language implementation) is because they are absolutely generic, being able to express any kind of aggregation of data by just passing different functions. As long as those are [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), they are *trivially parallelizable*, and can be implemented on multi-core machines or even internet-scale clusters without changing algorithm or result.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how first-class functions make it easier to perform parallel computing. Sure, map and reduce do seem handy as a way of compressing code, but how is this different than just straight up passing a `for` loop with the action you needed to each CPU? In both cases, eventually you have to send the code for the action itself anyway, so how does this help? Or is the extent of the benefit simply cleaner code? I think that perhaps I don't have a good grasp of what exactly mapreduce is.

Comment: First class functions provide the necessary abstraction to build a framework/functionality such as `map`/`reduce`. You can change the implementation of `map` from a dump `for` loop to something that is parallelised or distributed, but the code that uses `map` doesn't have to be changed at all. It's a separation of concerns (algorithmic functionality vs evaluation model) that keeps your code clean, yes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but how does this relate to Google's use of mapreduce? Perhaps I still don't truly understand what mapreduce is, but it seems like there's only so much benefit you can get from creating such a function and I don't see exactly how it was used to streamline their search.

Comment: What would the code look like without the `map` function? You'd have to repeat the for-loop all over your code base - and that's the simple case. What if you'd parallelise the computation? Much more code everywhere, much less focus on what each "loop" is actually doing. It helps to keep your code dry and separates the What from the How.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce was how google was doing their search in the early years leveraging lots of computers.

What I don't think is clearly communicated, is if you don't do the iteration yourself using for loops and use `map` then you can give it a function that takes a value and produces a new value, then the map function itself can work out how to do the work in parallel.

for loops can't work that out, you'd have to hand roll your own parallel implementation.   You can do parallel stuff both ways, nothing is stopping that. But it's more a question of what was is easier / simpler / less error prone

for a useful introduction to functional programming in js, you may want to have a look at https://drboolean.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/content/